# How to improve chances of a successful hero quest of a clan member?

Tags: king-of-dragon-pass

As far as I understand, the chances of success in a hero quest are all random meaning every try can fail. I know that there are certain answers which offer a higher probability of success than others, yet those are not what I am asking here.

What interests me is raising the overall chance to succeed at a quest.

I invest points in in Sacred Time, and take care that the one who performs the quest has the relevant god as their primary one, and when the quests allow I am asking for support.

Yet still they tend to fail quite often even killing the quester or sending them in limbo.

Should I sacrifice to the relevant god before the quest? Do certain gods offer blessing for quests?

How can I increase my chance of succeeding at a hero quest?

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate but offers relevant information: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/33349/how-do-i-know-which-cranky-old-dude-does-the-best-god-impression

Comment: Having an element of chance is not the same as being random…

Answer (score 1):

Performing Sacred Time rituals is a huge factor, as is not heroquesting too frequently.

The relevant god is important, but so is simply being able to pass the trials of the quest (I’m thinking of Elmal and Uralda in particular, but the overall better skilled a character is, the more likely they are to succeed).

And yeah, lots of info at the question you link to.